# How does IntelliJ decide if you're running a test?

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ separates a project's resource files into "Resource Folders" and "Test Resource Folders". My understanding is if you run unit tests, then it uses resources listed under "Test Resource Folders", and otherwise, will use "Resource Folders". The problem is that when running the same code, it seems to arbitrarily decide to switch from one to the other every once in a while. The only workaround I've found is to move each directory from "Resource Folders" to "Test Resource Folders" or vice versa when it happens, but the project is large with lots of resources, so IntelliJ ends up taking 10-20 minutes on the "Copying resources..." step.

Why is this happening and how can I avoid this problem?

Comment: If you're running a conventional Maven project, IntelliJ will automatically declare all resources under `src/test/*` as test-oriented.  When you say "arbitrarily decides to switch", it smells like you're not following conventions; then again, I'm not sure if you're using Maven, Ant, or Gradle - you haven't specified.  Could you provide some more context to this?  What indicators do you have to prove that IntelliJ is making this choice arbitrarily?

Comment: I have a Gradle project. The resource files in question are under src/main/resources. I'm saying it's seemingly arbitrary because I don't know what's causing it to make the switch, and that's what I'm trying to figure out by asking this question.

Comment: Are you using some sort of IoC container (Spring, Guice) in your main code?  If you are, are you injecting your dependencies via this resource folder?

Comment: No IoC containers are used as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Test resource roots are resources only referenced from tests, and resource roots are resources that can be referenced from both production and test code. The compilation process copies the resources and test resources of each module into separate output folders.

When you run a test run configuration (JUnit or TestNG), the classpath will include both production and test output folders; which of them takes precedence depends on the details of the test runner. When you run any other run configuration type, the classpath will only include the production output folders.

There is no logic in IntelliJ to use one resource root type *instead of* the other one. Either they're both on the classpath, or only one is.

Comment: Where can I check these things (run config, classpath, etc) to figure out what changed between each run?

Comment: The exact command line used by IntelliJ to start your application (including the classpath) is printed to the run configuration console.

Comment: It happened again just now. I ran a diff of the command used when it was working and from when it wasn't. The only difference was the debug port. Any other ideas?